# Database connection pooling for R parallel process

Tags: mysql, r, postgresql, parallel-processing

I have a database connection to `PostgreSQL` using the package `RPostgreSQL`. Currently I do the following:

1. retrieve a list from my database
2. run the list through a for loop, doing a calculation and writing the value back to the database

I am interested in parallelising this process. The obvious is to use the `foreach` functionality in the package of the same name. However, we need to use connection pooling: In this case I am interested if anyone knows a parallel backend which I can use to share my database connection. Here is a specific unresolved example:

[foreach %dopar% + RPostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902796/foreach-dopar-rpostgresql)

In the above case there is no connection pooling in the `registerDoMC` parallel backend, with the work around to open and close the connection within each `dopar` worker. Looking at the `registerDoSnow` parallel backend from the `snow` package also does not give this functionality.

The alternative would be to use `mclapply` instead of `dopar`. In this case, does anyone know whether or how to share the database connection with each `mclapply` worker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't share database connections between different workers in any of the general purpose R parallel programming packages because the workers are separate processes. However, you can create one connection per worker, and have the workers use that for each task that they execute. I discuss how to do that in an answer to the question [that you cited.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634121/2109128)

Comment: Thank you! I will have to try this but it looks very promising!